# Unresolved dependencies error while building hadoop 0.21.0

Tags: maven, hadoop, ant, mapreduce

I want to compile the mapred subproject of hadoop 0.21.0.
but I am facing dependency unresolved error.

```html
problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;0.21.0
[ivy:resolve]   ==== fs: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/[revision]/hadoop-common-[revision].pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;latest.integration!hadoop-common.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/[revision]/hadoop-common-[revision].jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/0.21.0/hadoop-common-0.21.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;0.21.0!hadoop-common.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/0.21.0/hadoop-common-0.21.0.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/0.21.0/hadoop-common-0.21.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;0.21.0!hadoop-common.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/0.21.0/hadoop-common-0.21.0.jar
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common-test;0.21.0
[ivy:resolve]   ==== fs: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common-test/[revision]/hadoop-common-test-[revision].pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common-test;latest.integration!hadoop-common-test.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common-test/[revision]/hadoop-common-test-[revision].jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common-test/0.21.0/hadoop-common-test-0.21.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common-test;0.21.0!hadoop-common-test.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common-test/0.21.0/hadoop-common-test-0.21.0.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common-test/0.21.0/hadoop-common-test-0.21.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common-test;0.21.0!hadoop-common-test.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common-test/0.21.0/hadoop-common-test-0.21.0.jar
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-hdfs;0.21.0
[ivy:resolve]   ==== fs: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/[revision]/hadoop-hdfs-[revision].pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-hdfs;latest.integration!hadoop-hdfs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/[revision]/hadoop-hdfs-[revision].jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/0.21.0/hadoop-hdfs-0.21.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-hdfs;0.21.0!hadoop-hdfs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/0.21.0/hadoop-hdfs-0.21.0.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/0.21.0/hadoop-hdfs-0.21.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-hdfs;0.21.0!hadoop-hdfs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/0.21.0/hadoop-hdfs-0.21.0.jar
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;0.21.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common-test;0.21.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-hdfs;0.21.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
/Users/Hassan/Documents/All My Techniques Source Code (Implemented)/CheckPointing Hadoop/Source Code/CheckPointing-Hadoop/mapred/build.xml:1861: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 11 seconds
Hassan:mapred Hassan$
```

The problem is I am facing the issue, that unresolved dependencies of three jars,
hadoop common-0.21.0
hadoop common-tesr-0.21.0
hadoop hdfs.0.21.0

I am actually building mapred of hadoop 0.21.0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to download those sources and compile/install them into your local machines Ivy repository. (And mapred package is deprecated anyway)

Comment: if deprecated, will it work?

Comment: Deprecated at Hadoop 2.0, so you should be fine

Comment: excellent, i follow your advice now its running awesome, but now i am facing deprecation warnings and errors in code, but code is fine, how to bypass this issue now?

Comment: I'm not sure what errors you're referring to. Warnings can be ignored, probably

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to resolve dependencies in this order

- Your local Maven repo - /Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/
- Apache Snapshots -
  https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
- Maven Central - http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

If it cannot find these, that means you either need to

1. Find, compile and install `hadoop-common:0.21.0`, `hadoop-common-test:0.21.0`, and `hadoop-hdfs:0.21.0` yourself.
2. Add a repository to the build configuration that does contain these versions.

It makes since that you need these because the `mapred` package has dependencies on them.

It also makes sense those versions are missing from the common repositories because Hadoop 0.21.0 is rather old.

Comment: bro, that part is done, as i follow your instructions: but now facing errors like this:




/Users/Hassan/Desktop/Native Hadoop/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java:56: error: package org.apache.hadoop.classification does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceStability;
                                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/Hassan/Desktop/Native Hadoop/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClusterStatus.BlackListInfo;

Comment: Yes, you're getting a new error, therefore you should accept this answer and make a new post.